# Handling of replication in hadoop's copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop

How is replication in hadoop's copyFromLocal handled?
Will copyFromLocal be slower if replication factor is > 1 when compared to replication factor = 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it will be slower. copyFromLocal is a kind of write operation. When the replication factor > 1, hdfs will have setup a pipeline to write the data from client to the datanodes on the pipeline. It will must take more time than just write the data to one datanode.

For more details about write. Go to [The design document](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12445209/appendDesign3.pdf).

Comment: I have a set of files(may extend upto 150GB) per day coming in which has to be loaded into HDFS.is there a better way to load data into HDFS?

Comment: Will using Flume or Kafka help me in loading data faster into HDFS

Comment: If your data is in a stream, Kafka should be a solution. Seems Kafka is designed to do such jobs.

Comment: Can convert the files to stream if needed, but want to know if i can load data faster using this approach or I should just go with copyFromLocal?

Comment: I have no experience on this. Maybe copyFromLocal or put is enough currently.